# How to keep sending signals to children from parent process repeatedly?

Tags: c, signals, fork, parent-child, ipc

I'm trying to get a program to create n child processes to read a file, and the parent keeps looping over them and trying to send a signal to keep reading the file if that process is free. Else, if that process is occupied, it moves to the next one. This is my approach  using signals, but the output is unexpected. And if i use printf to debug the code in the while loop of the parent, I only get the printf statements itself. Why is this happening?

From what I understand, the expected output is supposed to be all n child processes reading from the file almost at once (The file is small), and then an interval of 1 second before this happens again. Is this correct, or is this not certain due to race conditions?

I know that there may be a better way using pipes, but can this be possible using Signals? Thanks in advance.

- I know that signal() is not used as much as sigaction(), as mentioned in the man page, but can this be solved nevertheless?
- Could the unexpected output due to printf be because of the interference of printf itself with the IPC?

EDIT : Pastebin Link for testing : https://pastebin.com/ZWFnkJDA

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int counter = 0;
int fd;
const char* filename;
int j = 0;
int no_of_children;
int* cpid;

//User define signal handler
static void sig_usr1(int);
static void sig_usr2(int signo, siginfo_t* info, void* context);

static void sig_usr1(int signo)
{
    //Now the child process waits for reading the Filename

    //Block SIGUSR1 until it's complete
    signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN);
    printf("Blocked now.\n");
    printf("Child no %d is reading now.\n\n",getpid());
    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT);

    char buf = 'a';
    int k=0;
    char* op = (char*) malloc (255*sizeof(char));

    while(read (fd, &buf, 1))
    {
        if (buf == '\n')
        {
            op[k] = '\0';
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            op[k++] = buf;
        }
    }

    //Now wait for a second and then send a signal
    sleep(1);
    //Print the contents of the buffer via op
    printf("Output: %s\n\n", op);


    //Now unblock the signal
    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
    signal(SIGUSR1, sig_usr1);
    printf("Unblocked now\n");
}

static void sig_usr2(int signo, siginfo_t* info, void* context)
{
    if (signo == SIGUSR2)
    {
        child_pid = info->si_pid;
        printf("Parent Received SIGUSR2. Child Process with PID %d is now free\n\n", child_pid);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //Filename is the first argument
    filename = argv[1];

    //Number of Child Processes to be spawned
    no_of_children = atoi(argv[2]);

    cpid = (int*) malloc (no_of_children*sizeof(int));

    //Create a sigaction() handler for SIGUSR2
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = sig_usr2;
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &sa, NULL);

    //Create no_of_children children
    for(int i=0; i<no_of_children; i++)
    {
        cpid[i] = fork();
        if (cpid[i] == 0)
        {
            //Inside a child
            printf("Created %dth child process", i);
            printf(" with Process ID = %d\n", getpid());            

            signal(SIGUSR1, sig_usr1);

            while(1)
            {
                pause();
            }

            //Every child process must exit so control goes back to the parent
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    //Returns to the parent process
    while(1)
    {
        int fpid = cpid[j];
        //Send the signal to the free child process
        //printf("Sending to PID %d\n", fpid); //----> Uncommenting this line only prints this statement. Why does this happen?
        kill(fpid, SIGUSR1);
        j = (j < no_of_children - 1) ? j + 1 : 0; //----->Does not work as expected if i uncomment this line. I want to switch between PIDs and send signals to all of them
    }

    return 0;
}
```

- Sample Output:

```
$ ./a.out sample.txt 4
Created 0th child process with Process ID = 15734
Created 1th child process with Process ID = 15735
PID: 15737 -> PID: 15736 -> PID: 15735 -> PID: 15734
Created 2th child process with Process ID = 15736
Blocked now.
Child no 15734 is reading now.

Created 3th child process with Process ID = 15737
Output: This is a sample file

Unblocked now
Parent Received SIGUSR2. Child Process with PID 15734 is now free
Blocked now.
Child no 15734 is reading now.

Blocked now.
Child no 15735 is reading now.

Output: This is a sample file

Unblocked now
Output: This is a sample file

Parent Received SIGUSR2. Child Process with PID 15735 is now free
Blocked now.
Child no 15734 is reading now.

Unblocked now
Parent Received SIGUSR2. Child Process with PID 15736 is now free
Blocked now.
Child no 15735 is reading now.

Blocked now.
Blocked now.
Child no 15736 is reading now.

Child no 15737 is reading now.

^\%
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and raise the warning level of your compiler to the max. Trying to compile your example gives far too many errors.

Comment: I have edited my post to produce a working example. Can you check it out now? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, not now because I'm at work and there I have to use Windows. To increase your chances that others jump in you could also show which output you expected and what you got.

Comment: Yeah sure. I added the output as well. What I expected was the "Output" line to be displayed 4 times at once, every 1 second, because at that point, all 4 processes read the file

Comment: @thebusybee I actually got my problem resolved, but I don't know exactly why. So I simply removed the two `printf` statements when forking a child, and now it gives me my expected output. If I don't, apparently some child processes are not created for some reason. I don't know why this is happening..

Comment: `pintf` is signal-unsafe. Never do it in a signal handler.

Comment: @user58697 I get that, but the thing is, even with `printf` statements inside any signal handler, my program still runs fine. The statements I mentioned are the ones inside the `fork() == 0` block. Those are the ones which caused problems. If i didn't remove them, only 2 child processes get spawned, even if i wanted 10 of them. But again, since the parent keeps sending signals repeatedly, maybe that's the issue, even if the `printf` wasn't inside the handler?

Comment: With the source provided I watched no problems. All childs were created and read the file in turn. OK, the output is mixed up due to the process switching but each line was complete. I added the output of the PID to each line to see where it comes from. My system is Manjaro Linux, an arch derivative. I tried with GCC and clang.

Comment: BTW, `fork()` returns a negative number if there was an error. You could check this to see whether a child process was forked or not..

Comment: Concerning signal safety (or rather not) of `printf()` I would expect at least the starting message of each forked child, perhaps mixed with other outputs in the same line.

Comment: @thebusybee I have the same system (Manjaro), and I didn't get what you got. If I uncommented out the "Created 1st child process", I almost always get only 2 children spawned. And if i try to check, `fork() < 0`, and well, it's the same as before. Apparently, it does not fork all children for whatever reason if i include `printf`, even though it loops `n` times. Very strange.

Comment: @thebusybee I have edited the code block to show my problem. Can you try running that on your machine now to reproduce the problem?

Comment: `while(1)  {
                pause();
            }` There is no way to get out of this loop. So, your child process will never reach `exit()` Also:the`malloc()`in the signal handler is even worse than `printf()`. And it leaks memory, too.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, you're perfectly right, there are several issues to enhance (let's call it like that for now, we might view it as errors, too), but that's not the point here. We can discuss those after the problem is solved.

Comment: Good (in a sense), your unmodified source from Pastebin just prints 3 creation messages and that's it -- on my machine. So there is some kind of reproducibility. I then massaged the source a bit. To show you this, I'll continue in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: This is not ment as an answer, just some edited code and conclusions that might lead to a solution.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

int counter = 0;
int fd;
const char* filename;
int j = 0;
int no_of_children;
int* cpid;
int my_pid;

//User define signal handler
static void sig_usr1(int);
static void sig_usr2(int);

static void sig_usr1(int signo)
{
    //Now the child process waits for reading the Filename

    //Block SIGUSR1 until it's complete
    signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN);
    printf("%d\tBlocked now.\n", my_pid);
    printf("%d\tChild no %d is reading now.\n",my_pid, getpid());
    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY | O_CREAT);

    char buf = 'a';
    int k=0;
    char* op = (char*) malloc (255*sizeof(char));

    while(read (fd, &buf, 1))
    {
        if (buf == '\n')
        {
            op[k] = '\0';
            break;
        }

        else
        {
            op[k++] = buf;
        }
    }

    //Now wait for a second and then send a signal
    sleep(1);
    //Print the contents of the buffer via op
    printf("%d\tOutput: %s\n", my_pid, op);


    //Now unblock the signal
    kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
    signal(SIGUSR1, sig_usr1);
    printf("%d\tUnblocked now\n", my_pid);
}

static void sig_usr2(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGUSR2)
    {
        printf("%d\tParent Received SIGUSR2. Child Process with PID %d is now free\n", my_pid, cpid[j]);
        kill (cpid[j++], SIGUSR1);
        if (j == no_of_children)
        {
            j = 0;
        }

    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    my_pid = getpid();
    //Filename is the first argument
    filename = argv[1];

    //Number of Child Processes to be spawned
    no_of_children = atoi(argv[2]);

    cpid = (int*) malloc (no_of_children*sizeof(int));

    signal(SIGUSR2, sig_usr2);
    //Create no_of_children children
    for(int i=0; i<no_of_children; i++)
    {
        cpid[i] = fork();
        if (cpid[i] == 0)
        {
            //Inside a child
            my_pid = getpid();
            printf("%d\tCreated %dth child process", my_pid, i); 
            printf(" with Process ID = %d\n", getpid());            

            signal(SIGUSR1, sig_usr1);

            while(1)
            {
                pause();
            }

            //Every child process must exit so control goes back to the parent
            exit(0);
        }
        printf("%d\tforked %dth child -> %d\n", my_pid, i, cpid[i]);
    }

    //Returns to the parent process
    while(1)
    {
        int fpid = cpid[j];
        //Send the signal to the free child process
        printf("%d\tSending to PID %d\n", my_pid, fpid);
        kill(fpid, SIGUSR1);
        //j = (j < no_of_children - 1) ? j + 1 : 0;
        pause();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

OK, what did I do?

1. Add the PID of the current process at the beginning of each `printf()`. For this the variable `my_pid` was added and set at convenient places. Yes, I'm aware that some outputs gave this information already. I didn't want to change too much of the OP's source.
2. Removed double `\n` in the course. They don't help.
3. To see the success of `fork()` print its result.
4. Add a `printf` in the endless loop of the main process in the end. I wanted to see which process got signaled how many times at which rate. Wow, that was a lot!

Hm, could it be that the main process floods the child with so many signals that it can't even get to its call of `signal()` to block it temporarily?

4. Add `pause()` in the endless loop of the main process in the end.

Now things start to work, but most probably not in a way the OP wanted. Anyway, all child processes are created and receive their signals, reading the file, sending back their signals, and so on.

It seems there are too many signals in the system. The algorithm as such has to be thought over. So this is my advice:

- Make it slow. You could speed it up later.
- Put as many watch points (here: `printf()`) in the code to follow all events.
- Especially for multi-processing think about a way to visualize the results. I copied the shell output in an editor and indented the lines like this:

```
$ ./signal_repetition signal_repetition.c 4
1901                    forked 0th child -> 1902
    1902                Created 0th child process with Process ID = 1902
1901                    forked 1th child -> 1903
        1903            Created 1th child process with Process ID = 1903
1901                    forked 2th child -> 1904
            1904        Created 2th child process with Process ID = 1904
1901                    forked 3th child -> 1905
1901                    Sending to PID 1902
    1902                Blocked now.
    1902                Child no 1902 is reading now.
                1905    Created 3th child process with Process ID = 1905
    1902                Output: #include<stdio.h>
    1902                Unblocked now
1901                    Parent Received SIGUSR2. Child Process with PID 1902 is now free
1901                    Sending to PID 1903
    1902                Blocked now.
    1902                Child no 1902 is reading now.
1903                    Blocked now.
1903                    Child no 1903 is reading now.
    1902                Output: #include<stdio.h>
    1902                Unblocked now
1901                    Parent Received SIGUSR2. Child Process with PID 1903 is now free
1901                    Sending to PID 1904
            1904        Blocked now.
        1903            Output: #include<stdio.h>
            1904        Child no 1904 is reading now.
        1903            Unblocked now
        1903            Blocked now.
        1903            Child no 1903 is reading now.
1901                    Parent Received SIGUSR2. Child Process with PID 1904 is now free
1901                    Sending to PID 1905
                1905    Blocked now.
                1905    Child no 1905 is reading now.
        1903            Output: #include<stdio.h>
            1904        Output: #include<stdio.h>
        1903            Unblocked now
            1904        Unblocked now
            1904        Blocked now.
            1904        Child no 1904 is reading now.
1901                    Parent Received SIGUSR2. Child Process with PID 1905 is now free
```

- You could create a log for each process in its own log file. Add a timestamp with at least milliseconds resolution to synchronize all logs later. This way you avoid problems with mixed up output on `stdout`.

There are still enough other things to sort out. Have a lot of fun! And good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answering. Some of your points really helped. I agree with you; The parent sends way too many signals to the children is most likely the fault here. I did think of putting `pause` in the `while` loop of the parent, but didn't, as it wouldn't be the output I expected. But I agree with you, and your changes incorporate much better programming practices for me to follow. Learnt a couple of lessons via this question. Thanks again for your input!

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer, as this points out enough insights for me to complete my task